# Premature end of file. exception trying to parse xml from Zipinputstream

Tags: xml-serialization, xml-parsing, xstream, zipoutputstream

I am trying to extract an xml file & other contents from a ZipInputStream and create my objects from xml parsing the zipinputstream. However I am getting Premature end of file exception - for the following code or Stream Closed - when I dont have the while loop reading the inputStream. From what I understand, ZipInputStream.getNextEntry gets the next entries inputstream.

Also - when I run it by creating an actual temp file & pass the inputstream (as in the commented code) - it processes fine - but in my case, I wont be able to write to the disk - so all this has to happen in-memory. Can someone tell me where mycode is wrong and what can I do to fix it?

```
ZipEntry entry; 
Map<String, byte[]> otherElements = new HashMap<String, byte[]>();
        entry =((ZipInputStream)inputStream).getNextEntry();
        while (entry != null) {
            logger.debug("entry: " + entry.getName() + ", " + entry.getSize());
            System.out.println(entry.getName() + " - " + entry.getSize());

            if (entry.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Document.xml")) {
                /*File file = new File("C:\\tmp.xml");
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream();
                int read = 0;
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

                while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                    fos.write(bytes, 0, read);
                }
                InputStream fis = new FileInputStream();*/

                while(inputStream.available()>0){
                    inputStream.read();
                }

                myOutput = buildMyOutput((ZipInputStream)inputStream);
                //fos.close();
                //fis.close();
```

---

```
// method that takes the input and creates the java object
private MyObject buildMyOutput(InputStream xmlStream) throws Exception {

    // build my objects
    XStream xstream = ConvertUtil.getXStream();
    xstream.processAnnotations(MyObject.class);
    MyObject myOutput = (MyObject) xstream.fromXML(xmlStream);
    return myOutput;
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

found out what the issue is: 
XStream was losing the encoding information & setting it to null
[JIRA link on codehaus][1]https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/XSTR-441

so based on this input, i copied the inputstream as UTF-8 and then called the buildMyOutput method with the UTF-8 encoded format.
Removed the following snippet -

```
 while(inputStream.available()>0){
         inputStream.read();
 }
```

and changed the buildMyOutput call as follows

```
String xml = IOUtils.toString(zipInputStream, "UTF-8");
    InputStream documentXmlIS = IOUtils.toInputStream(xml);
    map = buildMyOutput(documentXmlIS);
```

Comment: I later realized that the real culprit was that my IDE was set to use UTF-8 by default instead of system default. So depending on which IDE you are using, it pays to check the encoding of the IDE as well (totally non-programmatic fix to a problem that sounds programmatic!)